# kubernetes resources and controllers

Tags: kubernetes

Using `kubectl api-resources` you are able get a list of all resources inside kubernetes.

Nevertheless, I'd like to know witch controller handles which resources.

For example, I've just installed `traefik` and I see some unknown installed resources:

```
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIGROUP                       NAMESPACED   KIND
ingresses                         ing          extensions                     true         Ingress
ingresses                         ing          networking.k8s.io              true         Ingress
ingressroutes                                  traefik.containo.us            true         IngressRoute
ingressroutetcps                               traefik.containo.us            true         IngressRouteTCP
```

Why are there two resources with the same name and diferent `APIGROUP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Kubernetes API evolves, APIs are periodically reorganized or upgraded. When APIs evolve, the old API is deprecated and eventually removed.

`networking.k8s.io` apigroup was introduced in v1.14.Currently ingress exists in both `extensions` and `networking.k8s.io` for backward compatibility and to give enough time for ingress controller implementations transition to `networking.k8s.io` from `extensions`.Ingress will be moved out of `extensions` in v1.22.